# Передача RtlCreateUserThread параметров

Tags: c++, c, многопоточность, winapi

В процессе создаю поток функцией `RtlCreateUserThread`

```
RtlCreateUserThread(hProcess, NULL, true, 0, 0, 0, (PVOID)GetProcAddress(hModule, function), NULL, &hThread, &cid);
```

В случае с функциями без параметров, например `ExitProcess` из `kernel32`, все работает нормально, но когда пытаюсь передать например `MessageBox` из `user32.dll`, не знаю как передать параметры этой функции (3-ий с конца параметр `RtlCreateUserThread`) такие как родитель, текст, тип и т.д. 
Как передать параметры (`PVOID StartParameter`)?

**Обновление**

Попробовал сделать так, объявил функцию

```
void message(){
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "text", "aption", MB_OK);
}
```

И вызвал `RtlCreateUserThread(hProcess, NULL, true, 0, 0, 0, &message, NULL, &hThread, &cid);`

Процесс крашнулся

> Thread tried write a virtual adress for wich id does not have the appropriate access

**Обновление 2**

Вызов делаю в чужом процессе. Нужна пока что просто для общего развития.
Насчёт прав странно, до вызова получаю токен доступа с `TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS` `OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &hToken);`
Да и процесс открываю с PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS `HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, PID);`

Comment: создайте свою функцию-обертку. Она будет получать указатель на структуру с аргументами. Внутри будет просто вызывать нужную функцию и подставлять правильные аргументы в правильные места.

Comment: А для чего вам настолько низкоуровневая функция? Воспользуйтесь обычным рантаймом. Или вы вызываете её в _чужом_ процессе?

Comment: А почему Вы используете недокументированную функцию? Там, как [выясняется](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsdesktop/en-us/44a504e4-d58d-40af-90c1-9db039718dd6/rtlcreateuserthread-on-64-bit) третий аргумент не просто bool, а однобайтовый.

Comment: Так и есть.
Вот импорт функции `EXTERN_C NTSTATUS WINAPI RtlCreateUserThread(
 HANDLE hProcess,
 SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR* pSec,
 BOOLEAN fCreateSuspended,
 ULONG StackZeroBits,
 SIZE_T* StackReserved,
 SIZE_T* StackCommit,
 void* StartAddress,
 void* Parametr,
 HANDLE* pThreadHandle,
 CLIENT_ID* pResult);`
Насчёт функции, опять же ради интереса

Answer (score 3):

А чем вас не устраивает функция [CreateRemoteThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Ну во-первых, вы можете передать только один параметр, поэтому и у стартуемой функции должен быть только один параметр. И победить это никак не получится.

Во-вторых, у функции `CreateRemoteThread` есть одна тонкость, я уверен что и с `RtlCreateUserThread` дело обстоит точно так же. Дело в том, что указатель `StartAddress` должен быть адресом запускаемой функции в пространстве удаленного процесса. То есть вы заранее должны знать по какому адресу размещена стартуемая функция в пространстве удаленного процесса. Вы же при вызове `RtlCreateUserThread(hProcess, NULL, true, 0, 0, 0, &message, NULL, &hThread, &cid);` указываете адрес `message()` из пространства вызывающего процесса. Поэтому и происходит падение. По этой же причине бессмысленно предавать указатель на локальную память в качестве параметра.

Но почему же тогда не падает в случае `ExitProcces`? Да потому, что `ExitProcses` во всех процессах расположена по одному и тому же адресу - так работает загрузчик. При запуске нового процесса он намапывает библиотеку kernel32.dll в адресное пространство самой первой (или одной из первых, не помню) так как без нее системные вызовы работать не будут. Но это поведение загрузчика не специфицировано и нет гарантии что завтра MS не поменяет логику и не начнет мапать kernel32.dll каждый раз по разному.

К стати функция `CreateRemoteThread` используется при реализации замечательной хакерской техники [внедрения dll](http://rsdn.ru/article/baseserv/IntercetionAPI.xml) для перехвата системных вызовов процесса.